# How to Deploy from github to Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure, github, deployment, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to deploy a basic angular 9 application to azure app services.

What I've done so far.

- I've Create a web app instance
  [image]

[image]

- Then I went to deployment center as the start up website suggested and hooked up my github  repository  via Deployment Center

[image]

- It added this workflow yml file to my repository I did comment out the npm run test becuase it is the default app for angular no need to waste time running the app

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - someapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up Node.js version
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12.x'

    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build -prod --if-present
        # npm run test --if-present
    - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v1
      with:
        app-name: 'someapp'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile}}
        package: .
```

- after running the pipeline, it gives a Application error with a 503 error code on the initial get.

I've tried ssh into the server to look at the file structure, but either i can't log in or if i do log in it kicks me off after a few seconds.

Does anyone know if i missed some step that is needed to deploy to azure or file structure thing I need to do? 
I've tried searching around for more up to date tutorials or questions but most seem pretty dated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App services is the wrong service for static websites.  I came across these docs that help me setup the website pretty quick. as Sajeetharan suggested you would have to use a devops pipeline to get the same effect as the deplyment center in app services for deployment.

1. Create a "Storage Account" and go to STatic website, and enable  Static website
2. Create a Project in Azure Devops the click on pipelines and create a new one. On the configure setp select Node.js with Angular. I linked mine with a github repository. This will add an azure pipeline yml to whatever deployment branch you selected.

You will need to produce an artifact, so you will need to add an extra task to your yml. e.g.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: dist/Nebulous
    artifactName: drop
```

Your complete yml should look like this

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: dist/Nebulous
    artifactName: drop
```

[useful link about adding artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

After this we are ready to push our artifact to our storage account

Go to Releases from azure Devops

3. Under the artifacts card click add, and add the Pipline that we just created to this. If you want continuous deployments click the lighting bolt at the corner and enable that.
4. Now Click the link under stage 1 that says "1 job, 0 task" then click The plus on the Agent job line to add a new task. Search for AzureBlob File copy.

Source: select your pipelines you made and navigate that to your artifact folder you mane in prior steps

destination type is Azure Blob

Select the storage account name you created earlier

Container name = $web

Now you can manually kick off or push into your branch and it will deploy to azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-static-website-node-01?tabs=bash

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two ways one way is to use the Github Actions , where you can build your own pipeline using actions. As this seems to be an angular app, follow my [blog](https://sajeetharan.com/2020/02/14/deploy-angular9-app-to-azure-with-github-actions/) on the same

2nd way is to use the Azure Devops Project, Create the Project and add bring your own custom code.

Regarding the actual error : I doubt if your files are deployed to the appservice, you can use Kudu to check if the correct files are there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the YAML I utilize for deploying an Angular App to Storage Account's Blob Storage. I didn't find the default Angular deploy worked for me. The pipeline would never run the second npm install command. You will need to be sure that under "capabilities" of the Storage Account, you enable "Static Website" which will create the $web container, beyond that, update the variables in the following YAML and it should work as-is.

Here is the entire YAML, and then I will explain it section by section to give more context:

```
variables:
- name: storageContainer
  value: myStorageaccount
- name: subscription
  value: Subscription (8217a062-4d59-45f6-bc03-b6f559a1e58a)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '14.17.4'
        force32bit: true
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: npm install
      inputs:
        script: |
          npm install
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: ng build
      inputs:
        script: |
          set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\node_modules\.bin;C:\npm\prefix
          ng build --subresource-integrity --output-hashing none
    - task: AzureFileCopy@2
      displayName: Deploy Files
      inputs:
        SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\dist\$(Build.Repository.Name)'
        azureSubscription: $(subscription)
        Destination: 'AzureBlob'
        storage: $(storageContainer)
        ContainerName: '$web'
        BlobPrefix: ''
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Delete Old Files
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(subscription)
        scriptType: 'pscore'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: 'az storage blob delete-batch -s `$web --account-name $(storageContainer) --if-unmodified-since $(Get-Date ((Get-Date).addMinutes(-5)) -UFORMAT +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ)'
```

Okay, here it is section by section:

The following sets the values for the variables storageContainer and subscription to be used in the rest of the commands. Variables are replaced when you use $(storageContainer) type syntax.

```
variables:
- name: storageContainer
  value: myStorageaccount
- name: subscription
  value: Subscription (8217a062-4d59-45f6-bc03-b6f559a1e58a)
```

The following sets continuous build / delivery when code is returned to the master branch, and tells everything to deploy to a vm with the latest build of Windows. Windows is needed for some of the azure cli commands later on:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
```

The following task installs node version 14.17.4 onto the system in order to utilize it. I had it utilize the 32-bit version of node, but that really shouldn't matter.

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.17.4'
    force32bit: true
```

The following executes the npm install and installs everything from packages.json. I added the angular/cli to my dev dependencies, and therefore its installed with this. If you don't want to do that, you'll need a command that installs the angular cli. Please keep in mind, Azure DevOps doesn't seem to like it when there is more than one node install within a CmdLine block, so you'll need another block.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: npm install
  inputs:
    script: |
      npm install
```

The following does the Angular build (ng build). The first thing I do is set the path appropriately so that it can find the Angular cli in the dev dependencies. I also have it add c:\npm\prefix to the path, which is apparently where the global npm installs are put. That was hard to find / figure out; so I left it in the path when I found it. In my Angular build I have two flags. The --subresource-integrity flag makes it so that the script tags have an integrity attribute that has the hash of the JavaScript file. This is considered a security best practice. I also have the --output-hashing none set. This makes it so that files are just main.js rather than the longer names with the hash in the JS file. This is just a preference of mine.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: ng build
  inputs:
    script: |
      set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\node_modules\.bin;C:\npm\prefix
      ng build --subresource-integrity --output-hashing none
```

The following Azure Cli command copies all of the files to the $web container of the storage account. The Angular build command by default putss these files from whatever is listed in "outputPath" in your angular.json. By default this is a folder under the dist directory. That folder happens to be the same exact name as my Git Repository, which I *think* is normal. This is why I have the source to grab files from be '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\dist$(Build.Repository.Name)' . I think this should work for you out-of-the-box the way I have it, but if not, replace "dist$(Build.Repository.Name)" with whatever is set in outputPath of your angular.json .

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@2
  displayName: Deploy Files
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\dist\$(Build.Repository.Name)'
    azureSubscription: $(subscription)
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: $(storageContainer)
    ContainerName: '$web'
    BlobPrefix: ''
```

When copying files to an Azure Storage Account, by default it will overwrite files with the same name. However, it won't do anything with files that are no longer used and aren't overwritten. For that reason, this last section will delete any files that haven't been modified in the last 5 minutes. This build process on average takes about 4 minutes, so I figured anything that was older than 5 minutes was from a prior build.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Delete Old Files
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(subscription)
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az storage blob delete-batch -s `$web --account-name $(storageContainer) --if-unmodified-since $(Get-Date ((Get-Date).addMinutes(-5)) -UFORMAT +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ)'
```

Hopefully this helps save someone some time. This took MUCH more time than I was expecting to get properly put together.